# awk only change matching line and print rest of lines without modification

Tags: perl, awk, sed, gsub

So I have a large file like the following:

```
RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST  arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXX:instance/i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST  arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXX:instance/i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname2
RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST  arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXX:instance/i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
..
```

I only want to modify the line with `RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST` and print the the other lines w/out modification.  Then I want to print only specific fields on the matching like, like below:

```
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname2
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
..
```

I was trying using awk gsub command, but really could not get the `-F:` part to work out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and it does not matter if it's awk, sed or perl.

Comment: please update the question with your `awk` attempt(s) and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: um ... so how do you get `arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX` from the rest of the line in the file?  why is `aws` not there? (the second field in colon-separated part?)

Comment: Are those (mulitple?) spaces or tabs between fields ... do they need to be preserved in output?

Answer (score 5):

With `awk`. I used as input field separators at least one space ( `+`) or (`|`) one colon (`:`).

If a row contains string `RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST` then print columns 2, 4, 5, 6 and stop processing this row and continue with next row. If a row does not contain `RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST` then print complete row unchanged.

```
awk -F ' +|:' '/RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST/{print $2,$4,$5,$6; next} {print}' file
```

Output:

```
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname2
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

One `awk` idea using the default field delimiter and `split()`:

```
awk '
/RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST/ { split($2,a,":")              # split 2nd field on ":" delimiter, storing results in array a[]
                           print a[1],a[3],a[4],a[5]
                           next                         # skip to next line of inpu
                         }
1                                                       # print current line
' sample.dat

# or as a one-liner sans comments:

awk '/RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST/ {split($2,a,":"); print a[1],a[3],a[4],a[5]; next} 1' sample.dat
```

This generates:

```
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname2
arn ec2 us-east-1 XXXXXX
TAGS    app-name    appname1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.30; # Perl v5.10 or above is required to use 'say' instead of 'print'
use warnings;

my $file = "datafile.txt"; #declare file name
open( my $fh, "<", $file ) or die( "Can't open `$file`: $!\n" );
#open the file with file handle $fh
while (my $line = <$fh>){ #read the file line by line
    chomp $line;      #remove line breaks
    if ($line =~ m/^RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST/){ #if line start with
        my @fields = split(/\t|:/, $line); #split in tab or : characters; each field becomes an element of @fields array
        say (join ' ', (@fields[1,2,3,4])); #join the relevant fields with a single space and print
    }else{
        say $line; #if line does not start with RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST, simply print it
    }
}
#when script finishes, Perl will automatically close the input file.
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that one keeps the fields 1,3,4,5 from the colon-separated part.

```
perl -wple'
    s{^RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST\s+(.+)}
     { join " ", ( $1 =~ /([^:]+)/g )[0,2..4] }e' file
```

With `-p` the variable `$_`, which has the line to process, is printed after the processing.

If that keyword isn't matched the regex does nothing and `$_` remains unchanged. If it matches then the whole line does and it, so `$_`, gets replaced with the return of the code in the replacement side. (With `/e` modifier the replacement side is evaluated as code, which extracts the select words separated by `:` in the rest of the line, captured in `$1`, and joins them by space.)

Or: test for the word, and either split the line and join the needed parts or print it as is

```
perl -wnlE'say 
    /^RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST/ ? join " ", (split /\s+|:/)[1,3..5] : $_' file
```

These are broken into lines so they are easier to read. They can be copy-pasted as they are (in bash), or brought onto one line.  Or, this can be written far more nicely in a file, but the question seems to be asking for a command-line program.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^RESOURCETAGMAPPINGLIST *([^:]+):[^:]+:([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+).*/\1 \2 \3 \4/' file
```

Pattern match and reformat as required.